# When is spring-retry @Recover called?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

In the spring-retry framework is the `@Recover` method called after all tries of the associated `@Retryable` method or is it called after all tries have been attempted and the method is still failing?

Answer (score 3):

It is called after all attempts have failed.

More correctly, it is called when the `RetryPolicy.canRetry()` method returns false; for a `SimpleRetryPolicy`, that means when `maxAttempts` have been tried (and failed).